# Why is pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN never equal to my Button, even when the user clicks on it?

Tags: python, oop, pygame

I'm currently working on a school project using Python and ideally, the project is to make any program using abstraction or algorithms in place. However, I'm stumped with this problem I've been having for days. I'm using Python with Pygame implementation to create a Vision Quiz, and I'm using buttons as multiple choice answers. Whenever I click on the correct button, it always says it's incorrect, and I have not been able to get past this part for a while. Please help me.

Pastebin link if needed: https://pastebin.com/BFPr6x6a
Code formatting here:

```
#Christopher Ticona
#Vision and Hearing examination

import pygame #All implementation of pygame itself

pygame.init()

#Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
yellow = (255, 255, 0) 

#Images
imageOne = pygame.image.load("imageOne.gif")
imageOne = pygame.transform.scale(imageOne,(200,200))
imageTwo = pygame.image.load("imageTwo.png")
imageTwo = pygame.transform.scale(imageTwo, (400,400))

#Messages and questions
welcome = "Welcome to my program! Let's get started. Today, we'll be examining your eyesight/color and hearing to see if you need any glasses or support for your sense. Don't worry, this could help your health!"
summaryProgram = "There will be multiple images and sounds when you're answering the exam to test yourself on hearing, eyesight, and color blindness. Be honest and don't judge yourself if you get it wrong! Good luck!"

questionOne = "1) What do you see?: "
questionTwo = "2) What's 1 letter from the 20/20 vision section?"

#Screen to display graphics
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1550, 720))
screen.fill(white)
pygame.display.set_caption("Vision and Hearing Examination")

class Button:
    def __init__(self, rect, command):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
        self.image = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size).convert()
        self.image.fill((red))
        self.function = command

    def get_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            self.on_click(event)

    def on_click(self, event):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
            self.function()

    def draw(self, surf):
        surf.blit(self.image, self.rect)


def button_was_pressed():
    if (pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN == answerOne):
        printText("You're correct! 1 Point", 15, 350, 100, black)
    else:
        printText("You're incorrect! Keep going!", 15, 350, 100, black)


def button_was_pressed1():
    if (pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN == answerTwo):
        printText("You're correct! 1 Point", 15, 350, 300, black)
    else:
        printText("You're incorrect! Keep going!", 15, 350, 300, black)

def printText(txtText, Textsize , Textx, Texty, Textcolor):
    #User's font
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', Textsize)
        #Input text
    label = myfont.render(txtText, 1, Textcolor)
    #Coordinates of text
    screen.blit(label, (Textx, Texty))
    #Show the full display
    pygame.display.flip()

def textButton(text,x,y):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)
    textsurface = font.render((text), True, (0,0,0))
    button_rect = textsurface.get_rect(topright=(x,y))
    screen.blit(textsurface, button_rect)

#Font is automatically Comic Sans MS (Change if needed)
#printText(Text, Size, X, Y, Color)
welcomingMessage = printText(welcome, 15, 5, 10, black)
explanation = printText(summaryProgram, 15, 5, 30, black)
questionOne = printText(questionOne, 15, 5, 100, black)
questionTwo = printText(questionTwo, 15, 5, 300, black)

#Images displayed to the quiz
screen.blit(imageOne,(700,100))
screen.blit(imageTwo,(600,300))

#Button(rect=(x, y, height, width), command=button_was_pressed)
#Question 1
btn = Button(rect=(25,120,105,30), command=button_was_pressed)
btn1 = Button(rect=(200,120,105,30), command=button_was_pressed)
btn2 = Button(rect=(25,180,105,30), command = button_was_pressed)
btn3 = Button(rect=(200,180,105,30), command = button_was_pressed)
#Question 2
btn4 = Button(rect=(25,320,105,30), command=button_was_pressed1)
btn5 = Button(rect=(200,320,105,30), command=button_was_pressed1)
btn6 = Button(rect=(25,380,105,30), command=button_was_pressed1)
btn7 = Button(rect=(200,380,105,30), command=button_was_pressed1)

answerOne = btn
answerTwo = btn6

done = False
while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True
                        exit()
                        quit()
                btn.get_event(event)
                btn1.get_event(event)
                btn2.get_event(event)
                btn3.get_event(event)
                btn4.get_event(event)
                btn5.get_event(event)
                btn6.get_event(event)
                btn7.get_event(event)
        btn.draw(screen)
        btn1.draw(screen)
        btn2.draw(screen)
        btn3.draw(screen)
        btn4.draw(screen)
        btn5.draw(screen)
        btn6.draw(screen)
        btn7.draw(screen)

        #Text over button
        #Question 1
        textButton("8", 90, 110)
        textButton("3", 250,110)
        textButton("7", 90, 170)
        textButton("18", 250, 170)
        #Question 2
        textButton("B", 90, 310)
        textButton("A", 250, 310)
        textButton("O", 90, 370)
        textButton("X", 250, 370)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Have you debugged to see what values you get in your callback?

Comment: However, `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` is an *event type*, it can never be equal to a button

Comment: The original title was unlikely to be helpful to anyone else, as it was specific to what kind of program you were building with pygame, as opposed to being specific to the behavior of the pygame API (and independent of the class of software in use). Keep in mind that Q&A entries should be written to be helpful to others encountering the same problem no matter what kind of software they're building.

Comment: Did not know that, I'm still learning about Python. Thanks for the help, and will try and make it more efficiently next time Charles.

Answer (score 0):

As @UnholySheep points out, you are passing a function, `button_was_pressed`, into your `Button` objects. That function contains this line:

```
if (pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN == answerOne):
```

Unfortunately, `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` is a contant provided by the pygame library - it may or may not be equal to `answerOne` once, but it won't always be equal to whatever "right" indicator you need (unless you make your questions always have the same answer, "always pick answer 'C'" or something).

Let me make a few suggestions:

1. Move your check for mouse button 1 into a separate function, taking an event:

   ```
   def was_mouse1_click(event):
       """Return true if event is a mouse button 1 down event"""
       pass
   ```
2. Write a method on Button to determine if a click was inside the button's area.
3. Write a function to decide which button was clicked, or None.
4. Clean up your code so that your main loop is short and sweet:

   ```
   buttons = [btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4]

   while not done:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if was_quit(event):
               done = true
               break
           elif was_mouse1_click(event):
               btn = which_button_was_clicked(event, buttons)

               if btn is None:
                   # click outside buttons? ignore
                   continue
               elif btn == right_answer:
                   celebrate()
               else:
                   wrong()
           else:
               # Not a quit, not a click, ignore it.
               pass

       # draw/update screen, etc.

   # broke out of while? we're done
   exit()
   ```